# Entity Framework and DetailsView in N-Tier Application

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, objectdatasource, detailsview, n-tier-architecture

I am absolutely new to Entity Framework so please don't hesitate to point any errors. Anyway I'll try to describe my problem as I understand it.

I am creating a n-Tier application with Entity Framework. I am also using a generic repository  as described in [this page](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/).

I was successful in populating a `DetailsView` and inserting a value to the database through an **ObjectDataSource**. However the problem I am encountering occurs when I am updating.

The error that I get is

> An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could
>   not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of
>   the supplied object match the key values of the object to which
>   changes must be applied.

And I understand WHY it happens as well. I use the following methods to populate the values from the DB.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
  return GetQuery<TEntity>().AsEnumerable();
}

public List<Company> GetAllCompanies()
{
  return _genericRepository.GetAll<Company>().ToList();
}
```

If I put a breakpoint in the `GetAll` method and observe the results I see that an`EntityKey` is set and `IsChangeTracked` is true for each object in the list.

But if I check the object passed to the `UpdateMethod` specified for the `ObjectDataSource`, then `EntityKey` is null, `EntityState` is detached and `IsChangeTracked` is false. So because the EntityKey is null, I understand the exception is valid.

My update method looks like

```
public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
    ObjectSet<TEntity> objSet = DataContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    objSet.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);
    SaveChanges();
}
```

I tried to attach using `objSet.Attach(entity);` then no exceptions but the object does not  get updated either.

How do I properly perform the update using DetailsView ? Or how do I properly bind an `ObjectDataSource` to a `DetailsView`? How do I make sure that my EntityKey does not become null ?

Comment: did you try changing the state to modified. `DataContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Object entity, EntityStat.Modified)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue using the method shown below

```
public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
    object originalItem;

    EntityKey key = DataContext.CreateEntityKey(GetEntityName<TEntity>(), entity);

    if (DataContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out originalItem))
    {
       DataContext.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, entity);                
    }

    SaveChanges();
}
```